# Parent Child Relationship Upto N Levels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build infinite level parent and child relationship.

In my requirement i am having parent libraries, in each parent library i am having list of publications  related to that particular library and child libraries.
In each child library gain we have publications associated with it and child libraries.... this process continues..

Can any one provide a sample code to achieve this .

This is my sample entity:

```
public class LibraryEntity
{
    //Library details
    public Guid LibraryGuid { get; set; }
    public string LibraryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    //Publications associated to this library
    public List<PublicationsEntity> pulications { get; set; }
    //Chils libararies
    public List<LibraryEntity> childlibraries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your code looks fine? Is there any issue with this class?

Comment: I want to know the logic, how to implement it. Just i designed the entity, but i don't know how to implement the logic to store the data into this entity

Comment: look like you're missing a `ParentLibraryGuid` property in your class, without it, you can't refer to `ParentLibrary` from `ChildLibrary`. And I want to know more about your requirement, what do you want to do with it? Implement CRUD operation?

Comment: What problems are you facing? It looks good. You only have to check if the child libraries collection is not empty and display the child libraries as links to the details.

Comment: If any fields are necessary in my class we can add them like ParentLibraryGuid and after retrieving the data just i want to display these details to UI (like parent library in that child libraries and so on ...)

Comment: I want the logic , how to store data into this entity upto infinite level, i was unable to get the exact logic , how to implement it @Carles Company